# Story in diary form about a malicious stranger who sets neighbours against one another

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for the name of a short story I read in a SF anthology in the early 90's, but I don't know the anthology's publication date.  I think the story was written before 1970.

The story develops over a series of diary entries, or in the form of reports to a home office.  An unnamed man moves into a suburb and begins creating mischief. He makes anonymous calls and spreads gossip as if he were making innocuous conversation.  He steals things and leaves them in neighbors' yards.  There is an African-American family in the neighborhood and he writes racist graffiti on their house.  He does other malicious things and leaves evidence to implicate other neighbors.  He ramps up the "pranks" as time goes on and by the end of the story the neighbors are at each others' throats and ready to kill one another.  As he moves out he records with some satisfaction that he's successfully set the entire neighborhood against one another and is ready to move on to a new "assignment".  He may actually work for some kind of agency or perhaps he's just a lunatic. It's never really clear.  The guy writing is almost like a travelling salesman; he seems logical and rational and he's very methodical.

Like I said, it was in a SF anthology, but it's not a SF story with futuristic elements, or special powers, nothing easily identifable as SF.  Not even sure why it was in an SF anthology at all.  Maybe because the author was generally a writer of SF.  I don't recall the name of the anthology but is was a grey hardback.  One of the other stories in the anthology was T. Sturgeon's *Shottle Bop*.  I'm not sure what other stories were in it, but it *may* have included Bester's short novel *The Stars My Destination*.  My various Google searches haven't been fruitful.

Comment: This is a Matheson story and it's not SF&F.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?72804

Comment: http://the.hitchcock.zone/wiki/Alfred_Hitchcock_Presents:_Stories_to_Be_Read_With_the_Door_Locked_(book) for one matching anthology

Comment: Man you are quick!  Thanks so much.  I actually had a flash and did a new search and found it in the Hitchcock anthology.  I was going to comment to that effect but you beat me to the punch. And yes, my memory was fuzzy, It isn't an SF anthology, which explains a lot.  In any case, I appreciate your comment.

I really like this story a lot and recommend it highly.  I also learned F. Paul Wilson wrote a kind of sequel entitled "Recalled" I'm going to try to acquire.  Thanks again FuzzyBoots.

Comment: Also, the Bester novel isn't in the anthology!

Comment: That's actually how I knew of Matheson's story. :) I read a copy of an anthology that collected famous authors writing stairwell stories to those of Matheson because I was a fan of Repairman Jack.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: The Matheson tribute volume is called "He is Legend" and has some pretty heavy hitters in it.

Comment: If it is not about speculative fiction, and it did not even appear in a speculative fiction anthology, I do not really see an argument that it is on-topic.

Comment: I read the story, and the only modestly SF idea is that there is an organization dedicated to making people suffer. The story even leaves open the possibility that he might have assigned *himself* the "job" of spreading suffering. But that is honestly a whole lot less SF than James Bond and other spy-fi (SPECTRE, anyone?) that we do not count here.

Answer (score 8):

The story you recall is Richard Matheson's "[The Distributor](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?72804)", and it appeared with "Shottle Bop" in *[Alfred Hitchcock Presents: Stories to Be Read With the Door Locked](http://the.hitchcock.zone/wiki/Alfred_Hitchcock_Presents:_Stories_to_Be_Read_With_the_Door_Locked_(book))*, which is not an SF anthology *per se*, but does contain some such stories.